# Neo4j: Cypher WHERE Clause vs. Curly Braces in MATCH Clause - Which is Better?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4J, and have been learning Cypher query language the past few days.

I realized I can write my query like this...

```
MATCH (b:Beverage)<-[:likes]-(p:Person)-[:likes]->(r:Restaurant) 
WHERE b.name = 'Beer' and r.name = 'KFC'
RETURN p.name
```

... or like this...

```
MATCH (b:Beverage{name:'Beer'})<-[:likes]-(p:Person)-[:likes]->(r:Restaurant{name:'KFC'}) 
RETURN p.name
```

Which approach is better in terms of performance? And why?

Thank you.

Comment: Those queries are identical in performance. It's just a matter of how you prefer to write the queries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm sorry to say, but @a-rodin's reply is wrong here: both of your statements result in the very same query plan. You can verify that by prefixing the statement with `EXPLAIN` and comparing the query plans.

For readability I'd structure the query in question:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:likes]->(b:Beverage{name:'Beer'}),
      (p)-[:likes]->(r:Restaurant{name:'KFC'}) 
RETURN p.name
```

Here the query reads like a sentence in plain English "match a person that likes beer and and like KFC restaurants".

Comment: Yes, you are right, I didn't know about the ``explain`` command.

Comment: Very helpful post, thank you. I didn't know I can break up `MATCH` statement with commas. Stumbled upon this article regarding using `EXPLAIN` for debugging purposes: http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-detecting-potential-typos-using-explain/